# Problemas al renderizar polyline con la libreria react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps

Estoy creando un mapa con google maps en react, necesito mostrar una polyline bajo la condicion de que si la sessionStorage esta vacia, la polyline no aparezca y si la sessionStorage tiene algun elemento, que este polyline se plasme en el mapa, por el momento, la polyline si aparece al momento de ingersar algun dato a la sessionStorage, el problema es que cuando se borran estos datos, la polyline permance, no se si sea algun problema de renderizado del mapa pero ya llevo dias tratando de solucionar este problema, lo curioso es que al momento de que se borra el sesion storage, el color de la polyline se atenua un poco:

Mapa al cargar el componente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mapa al agregar algo a la sessionStorage:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mapa al borrar todo en la sessionStorage:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del componente donde estoy creando el mapa seria el siguiente:

```
export default function Map(props) {
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_COMPONENT
  });

  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading..</div>;

  return <MapG allMapData={props.allData} />; 
}

  function MapG(props) {
    const [markersPositions, setMarkersPositions] = useState([{}]);
    const center = useMemo(() => ({ lat: 14.613781, lng: -90.515548 }), []);

    const [path, setPath] = useState([
      { lat: 14.58798122, lng: -90.52056885 },
      { lat: 14.58798218, lng: -90.52056885 },
      { lat: 14.5957613, lng: -90.51760864 },
      { lat: 14.59129047, lng: -90.5187149 },
      { lat: 14.59400463, lng: -90.51728821 }
    ]);
    
    const options = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      visible: true,
      radius: 30000,
      zIndex: 1
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
      setMarkersPositions(props.allMapData);
    }, [props.allMapData]);
    
    function handleMarkerClick(marker) {
      console.log(marker);
    }

    const onLoad = polyline => {
      console.log('polyline: ', polyline)
    };
    
    return (
      <div className="mapContainerPad">
        <GoogleMap zoom={15} center={center} mapContainerClassName="map-container" options={{disableDefaultUI: true}}>
        {sessionStorage.getItem('id') && (
        <Polyline
          onLoad={onLoad}
          path={path}
          options={options}
        />
      )}
        {markersPositions.map((marker, index) => (
          marker?.device_data?.Lat && marker?.device_data?.Lon && !isNaN(marker?.device_data?.Lat) && !isNaN(marker?.device_data?.Lon) ? (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              position={{ lat:  parseFloat(marker.device_data.Lat), lng: parseFloat(marker.device_data.Lon)}}
              onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(index)}
              />   
              ) : null
              ))}
              </GoogleMap>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías de usar `setMarkersPositions({})` para no establecer marcadores en `onButtonClick` para esto puedes usar una etiqueta `<button>` y le agregas una funcion `useCallback` para que vacié los datos y no marque las líneas, aunque tienes que asegurarte de que el componente mapa se inicie de nuevo/recargue pero sin las posiciones de los marcadores.

```
export default function Map(props) {

  function MapG(props) {
    const [markersPositions, setMarkersPositions] = useState([{}]);
    // ...
    useEffect(() => {
      setMarkersPositions(props.allMapData);
    }, [props.allMapData]);
    
    const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
      setMarkersPositions({});
    }, []);

    return (
    // ...
    // Agregar en la parte inferior al mapa
    <button onClick={onButtonClick} />
  }
```